# compare LIKE clause with complete word

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have the following `SQL` query that return all words contain `NANI`.

```
SELECT * FROM some_tbl WHERE q LIKE '%NANI%';
```

It's good when I have a sentence in my database like this:

> Nani was born in Cape Verde and emigrated to Europe with his family at
>   an early age.

But if I type just `NA` or `NI` with above query, that sentence will return again.

I need a pattern that compare the `LIKE` clause with complete word rather than a part of the word, any ideas?

Comment: are you considering only the "white space" as the delimiter?  Or special characters also? For example "My-NANI ...".  You may want to go with REGEXP instead of LIKE if you are considering special characters also as delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put blanks around your target string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_tbl 
WHERE q LIKE '% NANI %'
   or q LIKE 'NANI %'
   or q LIKE '% NANI'
   or q = 'NANI';
```

Comment: @DKN Updated answer to include "single word" case.